# Tensorflow cannot start a session on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I am running Tensorflow on Conda with GPU. Each time I get this error

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:353] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2018-10-09 11:58:43.850743: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:361] Possibly insufficient driver version: 390.48.0
```

I am on ubuntu 18.04 Lambda

It seems a driver problem. How can I resolve that?

Comment: You mention "Ubuntu 18.04 Lambda" in your edit. Do you mean you're running this on AWS Lambda?

Comment: @AKX no, on local machine

Answer (score 0):

> Possibly insufficient driver version: 390.48.0

sounds like you need to upgrade your Nvidia drivers. The way to do that depends on your distribution and how you've installed the drivers in the first place.

You can also try to downgrade your Tensorflow installation.